# LoginActivity Crashes during login

Tags: java, android

Don't no what's the problem,It's just every time i enter username and password
dialog box shows Attempting Login and app just crashes.
Server used:Wamp
Below are the codes used.
Any help would be appreciable.Thanks in advance.

LoginActivity.java:

```
package com.sam.kiet;    
import android.app.Activity;   
import android.app.ProgressDialog;   
import android.content.Intent;     
import android.os.AsyncTask;     
import android.os.Bundle;     
import android.view.View;      
import android.widget.Button;      
import android.widget.EditText;      
import android.widget.Toast;      
import android.util.Log;            


import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;       
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;     
import org.json.JSONException;      
import org.json.JSONObject;       

import java.util.ArrayList;     
import java.util.List;      

/**       
 * Created by Vaibhav on 10/2/2015.     
*/      


public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener                  {
   private EditText user, pass;       
   private Button bLogin;       
   private ProgressDialog pDialog;         
   JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();            
   private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://192.168.43.1/login.php";      
   private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";            
   private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";         
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Blogin);
    bLogin.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override    
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.Blogin:
            new AttemptLogin().execute();

        default:
            break;
    }
}

class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    //boolean failure = false;
    private String username,password;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Attempting for login...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
        username = user.getText().toString();
        password = pass.getText().toString();



    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        int success;

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            Log.d("request!", "starting");

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);
            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("Successfully Login!", json.toString());

                Intent main_activity = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(main_activity);
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);


            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String message) {
        super.onPostExecute(message);
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (message != null){
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
  }
 }
}
```

JasonParsor.java:

```
package com.sam.kiet;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader; 
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException; 
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser{

  static InputStream is = null;
  static JSONObject jObj = null;
  static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                  List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(final String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // Construct the client and the HTTP request.
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        // Execute the POST request and store the response locally.
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        // Extract data from the response.
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        // Open an inputStream with the data content.
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        // Create a BufferedReader to parse through the inputStream.
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        // Declare a string builder to help with the parsing.
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // Declare a string to store the JSON object data in string form.
        String line = null;

        // Build the string until null.
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        // Close the input stream.
        is.close();
        // Convert the string builder data to an actual string.
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // Try to parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // Return the JSON Object.
    return jObj;

   }
}
```

Login.xml:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp"
tools:context=".LoginActivity"
>

<!-- Login progress -->
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/login_progress" style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/login_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/username"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Username"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <EditText android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                android:imeActionLabel="Login"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Blogin"
                style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Login"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Logcat(error):

```
10-12 09:02:22.084    1804-1819/com.sam.kiet E/Buffer Error﹕ Error converting 

result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
10-12 09:02:22.084    1804-1819/com.sam.kiet E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
10-12 09:02:22.094    1804-1819/com.sam.kiet E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
    Process: com.sam.kiet, PID: 1804
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.sam.kiet.LoginActivity$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:92)
            at com.sam.kiet.LoginActivity$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:60)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
10-12 09:02:23.744    1804-1804/com.sam.kiet E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.sam.kiet.LoginActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{b1402280 V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,288} that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:346)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
            at com.sam.kiet.LoginActivity$AttemptLogin.onPreExecute(LoginActivity.java:71)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
            at com.sam.kiet.LoginActivity.onClick(LoginActivity.java:53)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

New LOGCAT:

```
10-12 10:40:56.083    5644-5658/com.sam.kiet E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value success of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
10-12 10:40:56.093    5644-5658/com.sam.kiet E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
    Process: com.sam.kiet, PID: 5644
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.sam.kiet.LoginActivity$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:85)
            at com.sam.kiet.LoginActivity$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:60)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
10-12 10:40:58.003    5644-5644/com.sam.kiet E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.sam.kiet.LoginActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{b1401ef8 V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,288} that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:346)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
            at com.sam.kiet.LoginActivity$AttemptLogin.onPreExecute(LoginActivity.java:71)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
            at com.sam.kiet.LoginActivity.onClick(LoginActivity.java:53)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what is line 92 in LoginActivity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: it is just used for debugging purpose.it just prints a lot of messages in log cat.

Comment: yes and the line is?

Comment: Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

Comment: NullPointerException is not hard to remove. I should debug the application and check from where the null is coming.

Comment: @Vaibhav are you still getting same error after updating with changes mentioned by meda or some other error

Comment: still getting same error NullPointer Exception.i have also updated the logcat checkout NEW Logcat

Comment: what I can see from logcat report including new changes...you have error in converting InputStream to String as mention by log "Buffer Error﹕ Error converting" so your json = sb.toString is not executed hence json is null...so you have multiple exception propogated...I would to know the logcat report line before   "Buffer Error﹕ Error converting " that is first line.

Answer (score 5):

ok I think you get the NullPointer because of this:

```
if(method == "POST"){
```

change it to

```
if("POST".equals(method)){
```

you compare the object reference and not the values with `==`.
That's the reason why the method `makeHttpRequest` returns `null`.

of course you have to change this too:

```
}else if(method == "GET"){
```

Comment: the other answers are also good. all together solves your problem

Answer (score 3):

This part of your code

```
Intent main_activity = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
finish();
startActivity(main_activity);
return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
```

You create the `Intent` then you `finish()` the activity , then you run `startActivity()` and finally return.

The logic order is wrong, try this approach:

```
class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
    //boolean failure = false;
    private String username,password;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Attempting for login...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
        username = user.getText().toString();
        password = pass.getText().toString();



    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            Log.d("request!", "starting");
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);
            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());
            return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        super.onPostExecute(json);
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (json != null){
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                String message = json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("Successfully Login!", json.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Login successful" + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent main_activity = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(main_activity);
                    finish();//only at the end!!!
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login failed = " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: its throwing an error "JSONExpection is never thrown in the corresponding try block "

Comment: Yeah remove the `try/catch`  block in `doInbackground`, I moved the parsing to `postExecute()` see my edit

Comment: did that but still crashing.

Comment: i did copy these code from here http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-an-android-user-login-system-using-mysql/31512 you can check it out it may help you debug it.

Comment: yes but you should be able to provide me the exact error log

Comment: checkout New logcat above

Comment: which line is throwing the error `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
 try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
```

to

```
 try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data",e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data",e);
    }
```

My guess is that you get a null pointer exception that the JSONException doesn't catch.

In general, I would suggest to check for null object before the try->catch since its much "cheaper" than the try->catch mechanism (which is very "expensive").

Comment: still crashing and now logcat has stop showing errors its empty

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);
```

change this to this

```
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "GET", params);
```

you are getting error because you are not getting Json so change your type and call the method again

Comment: still crashing after changing to GET

Answer (score 0):

Observing you code and both the logcat report...

**Initially you had a error will converting InputStream to String** which you handled with try catch hence due to `Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());` you can see it in first logcat report. This error was NPE with `InputStream is`. But at the end your method return null jsonObject This lead to multiple errors being propagated
**Solution Fix for this was given by @Stefan Beike Answer that is incorrect String comparison**

**Now you have error with json formation so your are getting error at mentioned in following code**

```
try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json); //LINE THROWING ERROR...
        //check properly String json if properly formatted json....so request for String json in question
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString()); 
        //Above line is visible in the second logcat report i.e new logcat.
    }
```

But again your method will return jObj which null...so in your doInBackground you get multiple error again
FROM new logcat report

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value success of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

> So if you want more help with fellow programmer then I would request
>   you to post the json string i.e. string after converting InputStream
>   to String in question.Alternatively you yourself can check the string is properly formatted JSON or not.